# How do I use Linq group by like this Code of Oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle, linq

```
  select count(*) Amount,
         (trunc(sysdate) - to_date(to_char(a."Admited",'yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd')) DiffDay
    from smartipd."Admits" a 
GROUP BY (trunc(sysdate) - to_date(to_char(a."Admited",'yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd')) ;
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `to_date(to_char(a."Admited",'yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd')` fragment, please? You just convert `DateTime` to `String` then back to `DateTime`

Comment: I want the result like the total number but when I use like "trunc(sysdate) - a."Admited"" I got result like "+13 14:45:04.000000" but when I use like this code it's work

Comment: For my purpose, I want to group data via the total of the differences between date in Linq.

Comment: Looks like you need just grouping by date without time part. That‘s right?

Comment: Yes, That‘s right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have your database available, I have to improvise using the Northwind database.  This will give what it appears you are going for in your code: The number of record, by number of days ago.

```
  from o in Orders
  let dffDate = (DateTime.Now - o.OrderDate.Value).Days
  group o by dffDate into c
  select new {Amount = c.Count(), Days = c.Key}
```